# How do I put a button and a set of buttons next to each other in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've a login page that contains of sign in fields (email/password) and sign in buttons.

[Initial look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dy6lF.png)

I want the buttons `New account` and `Forgot password` to be next to the button `Login`, but still above each other like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcuRv.png)

This is my code [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5m23/4/)

```css
page-login {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position-y: 50%;
  .logo {
    display: block;
    width: 1050px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
  }
  button {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 7px;
    border: none;
  }
  .facebook-btn,
  .google-btn {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    border: none;
    background: #939393;
  }
  #btn button {
    padding: 3px;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    background-color: Transparent;
    color: black;
  }
  #btn {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .norm-login-textfield {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 5%;
  }
  .norm-login-field {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 55%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 5%;
  }
  .icons {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .error {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(217, 74, 87);
    p {
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
  .invalid {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF6153;
  }
  ion-input {
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="loginUser()" novalidate>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address" [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.email.valid && loginForm.controls.email.dirty"></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="ios-mail-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.email.valid  && loginForm.controls.email.dirty">
      <p>Please enter a valid email.</p>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.password.valid && loginForm.controls.password.dirty"></ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="ios-key-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="error-message" *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.password.valid  && loginForm.controls.password.dirty">
      <p>Your password needs more than 6 characters.</p>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" style="margin:0 auto;width:100px;height:100px;">
              Login
            </button>

  </form>
  <div id="btn">
    <button ion-button clear (click)="goToSignup()" style="margin:0 auto;">
            New account
          </button>

    <button ion-button clear (click)="goToResetPassword()" style="margin:0 auto;">
            Forgot password
          </button>
  </div>

  <button ion-button block class="facebook-btn" (click)="facebookLogin()">
             <ion-icon name="logo-facebook" class="icons"> </ion-icon>
              Login with Facebook</button>

  <button ion-button block class="google-btn" (click)="googleLogin()">
             <ion-icon name="logo-google" class="icons"></ion-icon>
              Login with Google</button>


</ion-content>
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle for your issue, it will help us to track coz nobody will read your code :p

Comment: @George W #btn{display:inline-block}

Comment: simple way would be to put everything in a table

Comment: @Dhaarani: That returns returns the buttons to left side of the page. It doesn't put them next to each other

Comment: @George W check my answer

Comment: Your included code doesn't contain enough css to reproduce the layout you describe, specifically the look of your button elements don't match. Please include sufficient code that we can reproduce your problem as described, and shown.

Comment: @DavidThomas: I have copy/pasted the whole CSS file I have :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
      controller: "LoginCtrl"
    })
  
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
})

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {};

        $scope.login = function (user) {
            console.log('Logging In', user);
        };
})
```

```css
page-login {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position-y: 50%;
  .logo {
    display: block;
    width: 1050px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
  }
  button {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 7px;
    border: none;
  }
  .facebook-btn,
  .google-btn {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    border: none;
    background: #939393;
  }
  #btn button {
    padding: 3px;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    background-color: Transparent;
    color: black;
  }
  #btn {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .norm-login-textfield {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 5%;
  }
  .norm-login-field {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 55%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 5%;
  }
  .icons {
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .error {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(217, 74, 87);
    p {
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
  .invalid {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF6153;
  }
  ion-input {
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
form,div#btn {
    display: inline-block;
}
#btn button,button.google-btn,button.facebook-btn {
    display: block;
}
ion-content.scroll-content.ionic-scroll.scroll-content-false {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#btn button, button.google-btn, button.facebook-btn {
    display: block;
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
    line-height: 14px;
}
form, div#btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: sub;
}
button.button.button-block.button-outline.button-positive {
    background: orange;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.padding.login {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp"><head><style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}</style>
    </head>
<body ng-app="ionicApp" class="grade-a platform-browser platform-win32 platform-ready">
    

  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    
    <title>Login Example</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  

  
    <ion-nav-view class="view-container" nav-view-transition="ios" nav-view-direction="none"><ion-view class="pane" nav-view="active" style="opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px);">
    <ion-content scroll="false" class="scroll-content ionic-scroll scroll-content-false">
        <form ng-submit="login(user)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-email ng-submitted">
            <div class="list">
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <i class="icon ion-email placeholder-icon"></i>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-email">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="password">
  </label>
            </div>
            <div class="padding login">
                <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-outline button-positive">
                    <i class="icon"></i>
                    Log in
                </button>
            </div><div id="btn">
    <button ion-button="" clear="" (click)="goToSignup()">
            New account
          </button>

    <button ion-button="" clear="" (click)="goToResetPassword()">
            Forgot password
          </button>
  </div>
        </form>
        

    </ion-content>
</ion-view></ion-nav-view>
  
  
  <script id="templates/login.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="Login">
    <ion-content scroll="false">
        <form ng-submit="login(user)">
            <div class="list">
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <i class="icon ion-email placeholder-icon"></i>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
  </label>
            </div>
            <div class="padding login">
                <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-outline button-positive">
                    <i class="icon"></i>
                    Log in
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="btn">
    <button ion-button clear (click)="goToSignup()">
            New account
          </button>

    <button ion-button clear (click)="goToResetPassword()" >
            Forgot password
          </button>
  </div>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Meaningful solution +1

Comment: Just explain in few words what you've did.

Comment: @Sankar Raj I am just changed block element to inline using display:inline-block and inline element to block using display:block css property

Answer (score 0):

To have them together and centered place them in a div and give it the

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

then give the login button an id (eg. #login-button) and use

`display: inline-block;`

on both #login-button and #btn

Answer (score 0):

Place all three of the buttons in a **div** with:

```
margin:0 auto; width:200px;
```

Give the buttons the following styles:

**1st button:**

```
float:left; width:100px; height:100px;
```

**2nd + 3rd buttons:**

```
float:right; width:100px; // or fewer pixels - adjust to fit padding/margins
```